# What is package naming convention used in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is there a naming convention for Dart packages? Is there maybe a document that describes patterns? I have trouble figuring out naming convention for package names that consist of multiple words. For example, should I use `placeView`, `PlaceView`, `place_view`, or something else?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is documented on the [name section](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pubspec.html#name) of *Pubspec Format documentation*.

> It should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate words, `just_like_this`. Stick with basic Latin letters and Arabic digits: `[a-z0-9_]` and ensure that it’s a valid Dart identifier (i.e. doesn’t start with digits and isn’t a reserved word).
>
> Try to pick a name that is clear, terse, and not already in use.

Comment: Actually this is documented. See [the answer of @nex3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419909/634863)

Comment: Correct. Changing the directory to **lower_case** format helped.

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be a convention for it, but most of the time, I see `lowercase_words_with_underscore` being used, both for libraries and packages.

For libraries inside packages, some people also use dots for grouping, for example `my_package.lib_1` and `my_package.lib_2`.

It's all personal preference, I guess.

Comment: The style guide covers the names of libraries and source files but not the naming of packages. But I agree it's almost the same thing.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin I totally got those two confused. But yeah, the lowercase_with_underscore holds true for both.

Answer (score 5):

You only can create flutter project by lowercase and no space between the project name and avoid to add special characters. 
Follow these steps you will not get any error like this.

```
"ProjectName" is not a valid Dart package name.


From the [Pubspec format description](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec.html):

**DO** use `lowercase_with_underscores` for package names.

Package names should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate words,
`just_like_this`.  Use only basic Latin letters and Arabic digits: [a-z0-9_].
Also, make sure the name is a valid Dart identifier -- that it doesn't start
with digits and isn't a reserved word.
```

Comment: flutter may use the folder name as the package name, so if your folder has a dash in it (`-`) or some other non 0-9, a-z character, then rename the folder and try again

Answer (score 4):

All the package conventions are documented on [pub.dartlang.org](http://pub.dartlang.org). The package naming conventions in particular are documented on [the pubspec format page](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pubspec.html).

Answer (score 1):

I only found this
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5094

- That the package name follows the naming conventions (valid Dart identifier, doesn't conflict with any reserved words, all lower case).

Answer (score 1):

**- Naming convention summary -**

Dart uses 03 naming convention methods.

1. UpperCamelCase
2. lowerCamelCase
3. lowercase_with_underscores

---

**01. UpperCamelCase**

- Classes  ( *eg:-* MyClass )

  ```
  class MyClas { ... }
  ```
- enum  ( *eg:-* Status )

  ```
  enum Status { none, running, stopped, paused }
  ```
- typedefs    ( *eg:-* Signature )

  ```
  typedef Signature<T> = bool Function(T value);
  ```
- type parameters   ( *eg:-* T )

  ```
  class Foo<T extends Object> { ... }
  ```
- extension   ( *eg:-* MyMethod )

  ```
  extension MyMethod<T> on List<T> { ... }
  ```

**02. lowercase_with_underscores**

- packages

  > *eg:-* hive_flutter, url_launcher, flutter_svg
- directories *(mostly lowercase only)*

  > *eg:-* lib, bin, src, test, example
- source files

  > *eg:-* main.dart, home.dart
- import prefixes

  > *eg:-* import 'dart:math' as math;

  > *eg:-* import 'dart:math' as my_math;

**03. lowerCamelCase**

- Class members (instance/static methods and variables)

  > *eg:-* void myFun() {}, int studentRank = 1;
- top-level definitions

  > *eg:-* double topVariable;
- variables

  > *eg:-* int myValue = 3;
- parameters (both positional and named)

  > *eg:-* void fun({int myParam}){...} ,  void fun(int myParam) {...}

---

**In your case (for packages),  you have to use *"lowercase_with_underscore".***

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

If you are like me you will face a challenge if your `app_name` begins with a digit.
My App name begins with a number so my solution was to change the number `"1"` into the word `"one"`

Its some of these small differences you have to watch for.