# AppLocalization class not found when trying to run the app flutter

Tags: flutter

My app works fine on android but when I try to launch it on iOS I get a huge error and mostly mentioning this

> The getter 'AppLocalizations' isn't defined for the class '_home_mainState'.
>        - '_home_mainState' is from '../../Documents/GitHub/pocketcarage-official/lib/Customer/ui/home_main.dart'.
>       Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'AppLocalizations'.
>                         frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("Tyres"), _foldingCellKey2, 2),

and it keeps on mentioning the same error for multiple different usage places but the class is there

here is a screen shot of the project files

[image]

What I tried is build with Xcode instead of android but still the same problem and in addition extra classes or plugins becomes not found like firestorm

also I tried deleting and creating the pod file 
also tried updating pods

Comment: please give class name in small letters. Dart does not support Caps letter class.

Comment: @amit brother dart supports capital class names its not the problem I even tried to put it in lower case but no use as I mentioned it works fine on android only on iOS doesnt work

Comment: please read guideline carefully and look this(file name must be in lowercase using underscore) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401244/what-is-package-naming-convention-used-in-dart/21419909#21419909) this may be the reason Xcode is not reading your file and also try clean the project once.

Comment: Yes I saw the link you sent it doesnt say a convention its a (way to do approach) not a must

Answer (score 13):

**If cleaning doesn't work, you can remove the errors by restarting the Dart analysis server. In VS Code: `Control+Shift+P` and type `Restart analysis server`**

You can also generate the translation again if you added a new translation with the app running so you can hot-restart without rebuilding the app.

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

Comment: `ctrl+shift+P` and `restart analysis server` is the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Running `flutter clean` and rebuilding the Flutter project should help map the missing class on your iOS build.

Comment: A vital step is to run flutter pub get after running flutter clean

Comment: `flutter pub get` seems to be automatically executed when the app is run after `flutter clean`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Do three things:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. Open the `AppLocalizations` class in its file here:[image]