# The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:

Tags: android, flutter, device

My device can connect to other projects but why didn't it connect only this project What can I add to the project

PS C:\Users\timur\Desktop\Flutter-Slide-Puzzle-Hummingbird-master> flutter run

`No supported devices connected. The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project: SM J260F (mobile) • 42007b95e43465bd • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) If you would like your app to run on android, consider running` flutter create . `to generate projects for these platforms.`

I run "flutter create ." in terminal but this error is shown

`Flutter-Slide-Puzzle-Hummingbird-master" is not a valid Dart package name.`

Comment: See [What is package naming convention used in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401244/what-is-package-naming-convention-used-in-dart) – you can't use dashes in the package name.

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax:
Flutter_Slide_Puzzle_Hummingbird_master